# Open specific excel sheet from sharepoint URL

Tags: url, spreadsheet

I have one excel with sheets ( Sheet1 and Sheet2) uploaded in sharepoint.

Requirement : to create a URL to access the uploaded excel document and open specific sheet (say Sheet2)

Any solutions here?

Comment: Do you want a URL to open exact sheet in browser using Excel Web App? What is your SP version & edition?

Comment: SP 2007  and Version 12.0.0.6421

Comment: Yes want to open exact sheet . doesn't matter if it opens the sheet in excel  client.

Comment: I tried opening the sheet by adding hyperlink for URL (http://path/to/Workbook.xls#SheetName!a1)  in worddocument. It opens specific sheet ; however, it does not open if i direct access the same URL from browser.

Answer (score 4):

> ?web=1

works to open the spreadsheet in a web browser, thanks to @Vincent Crenshaw but

> ?range='YourWorksheetName'

doesn't work. Finally, this works for me:
https://superuser.com/a/1115331
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/227779/99645

> replacing &action=default with &activeCell=%27Sheet1%27!A2

is the key!

```
https://your.sharepoint.com/:x:/s/sitename/shortURL&activeCell=%27Sheet1%27!A2
```

Comment: There is another key... the base URL for me could not be the one you obtain by going in Excel desktop app > File > Info > Copy Path. Instead I absolutely had to use the URL that's used when you're using the web view of the workbook (it automatically redirects to this one when you use web=1). From there, replace just how you described - that is, swap action=default for the activeCell=STUFF

Answer (score 3):

That `#` symbol in URL usually divides an `address` and `fragment location`, and fragment location is never transmitted to server, but handled by client. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier :

> In URIs a hashmark # introduces the optional fragment near the end of the URL ... The fragment identifier functions differently than the rest of the URI: namely, its processing is exclusively client-side with no participation from the web server

So there's nothing SharePoint Server should do here, cause handling of `#...` part is a client app's job. And regarding those clients: You can use `https://site/lib/workbook.xlsx#'Sheet1'!A1` links in **some** Office application. I can confirm those specific links are handled well in Excel / Word / PowerPoint, and had never seen them work in Project / Visio / Outlook.

This is how it actually works: fragment-aware application parses the URL, and launches Excel telling to open the document at `https://site.lib/workbook.xlsx` and then passes *'navigate to specific object' command* with `#...` part of URL as an argument to Excel. In VBA this is done with something like `Application.Goto Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")`.

That clients are 'smart'. Browsers are not.

So the answer is **yes, you can** create that kind of links to Excel files stored in SharePoint with `#...!...` notation, **but** they will only work in context of other Office application.

Comment: Also see p.2 in https://blog.httpwatch.com/2011/03/01/6-things-you-should-know-about-fragment-urls/

Answer (score 0):

The URL will be something like:

```
http://path/to/Workbook.xls#SheetName!a1
```

Reference:https://superuser.com/questions/205728/how-do-you-specify-a-specific-worksheet-to-open-for-a-ms-excel-workbook-using-a

Comment: I did try with http://path/to/Workbook.xls#SheetName!a1  also tried with  http://path/to/Workbook.xls#'SheetName'!a1  , but no luck. Whenever i try with URL , it downloads the file from the browser and when you open it opens the last saved sheet

Answer (score 0):

First create a named range for the table or data on the spreadsheet you want to link to. Now that I think of it I don't think it's necessary. But do it if all else fails. :-)

At the end of your file path add this ?web=1?range='YourWorksheetName' Where YourWorksheetName will be the name of the worksheet or the table range name.

Your final path will look something like this assuming it's an excel you are linking to in a SharePoint data library...

http://xxx/xxxxxx/xx/archmetrics/Data%20Library/3Q%202018%20Reporting.xlsx?web=1?range='TimeInPhase'

Answer (score 0):

Peter Wangxin's solution worked for me!

https://your.sharepoint.com/:x:/s/sitename/shortURL&activeCell=%27Sheet1%27!A2

Comment: please add the content from the blog rather than just sharing link.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/122061)

Answer (score 0):

Right click on a sheet tab in web version of Excel and there's a menu position which gives you possibility to get the link for specific sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Excel using the browser and Navigate to the sheet (Tab). Then select Share->Copy Link to This Sheet.