# Link to Visio Shape from SharePoint 2013 List?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, hyperlink, visio, visio-services

I'm working on creating a floorplan for our large office from a SharePoint "Employee Directory" list.  The Visio drawing will be posted to our SharePoint which will be accessed using the Visio services web part. The drawing is linked to the "Employee Directory" list, so changes to the list (employee moves cubes, leaves, starts, etc.) is reflected in the drawing.

What I'm trying to make happen is for our staff to go to the "Employee Directory" list, find someone's name in the list, click on their cube number in the next column over, and have that cube number be a link to the appropriate cube in the Visio drawing.

I've spent several hours researching this and I am coming up with nothing.  Is this something that's even possible?

I'm using Sharepoint 2013 and Viso 2013 Professional.

Thank you for any and all help/advice!

Comment: https://cypher19.wordpress.com/creating-a-floor-plan-with-visio-for-use-in-sharepoint-2010/ Is this what you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

Visio does support [hyperlinks](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-a-hyperlink-271fb2a8-4081-47db-a333-487315c05085) with sub-address:

[image]

Here you see `dest.vsdx` file with some random shapes and Drawing Explorer open, and `source.vsdx` file with single shape that have a text converted to **hyperlink** with sub-address. Also notice `zoom=400` is specified and is respected too.

These files are local on my PC, and it works perfectly.

- If I place both files to sharepoint.com site document library and open `source.vsdx` in desktop Visio, then the hyperlink works too.
- If I open `source.vsdx` in Visio **Web Access**, then hyperlink is `https://{something}.sharepoint.com/Documents/dest.vsdx#Page-1/Data?zoom=400`, download is initiated on click, and downloaded file is opened in default view - the bookmark is **not working**.

I've written a note about **fragment locations in Office Documents** [here on SP.SE](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/172039/50547), but that was left ignored by original question author. Basic idea is: if browser gets involved, then fragment information is lost, cause it never goes out of the calling application, and `Page-1/Data?zoom=400` part never reaches server, and desktop Visio has no idea there was some sub-address.

So we need to know if it's possible to modify the hyperlink to point to address like `https://{something}.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/VisioWebAccess/VisioWebAccess.aspx?id=/Documents/dest.vsdx#Page-1/Data?zoom=400` instead of
`https://{something}.sharepoint.com/Documents/dest.vsdx#Page-1/Data?zoom=400`.

Sure it is, but **VisioWebAccess.aspx ignores fragment location**, and that's a real problem. It opens the diagram, but does not focus/zoom. If that worked out, you could populate a column in SPList with `/_layouts/15/VisioWebAccess/VisioWebAccess.aspx?id=/diagram.vsdx#Page/Shape` links and use it to implement that 'click to view a diagram' function.

Maybe you'll manage to somehow reinterpret the idea and find a solution. Then please share.

There is not so much topics & questions on using subaddresses in Visio Web Access in the Internet. Most effective "*solution*" I've found is from a guy that dumped the idea and used PDF with named destination.