# Open a specific Workbook in Excel online using the URL in SharePoint online Excel Workbook

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, excel, excel-online

I have 2 sheets inside the excel file i just want to link different sheet using url in different page is there any way that i can open the specific sheet of excel file using the url in the browser i am using Sharepoint Online(Excel Online) and i also followed this article below but it is not opening in the browser or opening the specific tab.

[Open specific excel sheet from sharepoint URL](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/172007/open-specific-excel-sheet-from-sharepoint-url)

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

/_layouts/15/WopiFrame.aspx?sourcedoc=ID&file=filename.xlsx&action=default

replace "action=default" with "activeCell=%27sheetname%27!A1" set active cell in the link, and specify sheet and cell. where Sheetname is the name of the worksheet you're linking to, and !A1 is the name of the cell on this worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

I spent way too long on this very problem. My use case was simpler: I maintain a fairly complex set of account data in Excel and needed to expose certain reports on it (pivot tables, queries) to salespeople.

Appending `ActiveCell=CellName` didn't work but using the `Item=itemName` URL parameter did. I just made sure that every table had a unique name. I then grabbed the Sharepoint URL from Share | Copy Link and appended the appropriate parameter, e.g., `Item=report_name_of_table`.

Not pretty, but it worked.