# How to open an Excel file in Excel online on button click in SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, jsom, excel-online

I need to open an excel file in **Excel online** on a button click which I retrieves from *Document library* .

I have followed [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/227778/open-a-specific-workbook-in-excel-online-using-the-url-in-sharepoint-online-exce), but it shows me an Error page like **'Item does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user.'**

Please suggest.

Comment: Do you want to do by Code with JSOM or Rest ?
Or just to do in OOB ?

Comment: JSOM or REST both will work for me!

Comment: If OOB is available for this, then please do suggest...

Comment: With help of modern experience applied in your libraries you can open excel online.

Answer (score 1):

I have done it something like this, please suggest if this is a good approach or not?

```
excelOpen(objItems[i].__metadata.uri);
   <a id="openExcel" target="_blank" onclick=excelOpen("' + objItems[i].__metadata.uri + '");>Click to view </a>' + '</td>'; 

function excelOpen(path){//,type
var p = GetDocUID(path);
    p.done(function(_resultpath){
        $('#openExcel').attr('href',_resultpath.d.ServerRedirectedEmbedUrl);
     });
}
function GetDocUID(path){
var defReturn = $.Deferred();
var url = path+"?&$select=ServerRedirectedEmbedUrl";
console.log(url);
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "GET",
    headers: {
      "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    },
    success: function(results) {
    defReturn.resolve(results);
    },
    error: function(error) {
      defReturn.reject(error);
      console.log("Error in getting List: " + listName);
    }
  });
return defReturn.promise();
}
```